Aws codepipeline variable access inside action
i have a variable that is on the pipeline level and I'm trying to access on a certain stage, but I'm not able to retrieve its value during run time.
Variable definition:
pipeline.addVariable(
  new Variable({
    variableName: "stage",
    defaultValue: "test",
    description: "env",
  }),
);

const buildProject = new codebuild.PipelineProject(stack, "BuildProject", {
  buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject({
    version: "0.2",
    phases: {
      install: {
        "runtime-versions": {
          nodejs: "20",
        },
        commands: [
          "npm install -g pnpm",
          "pnpm install --store-dir=/root/.pnpm-store",
        ],
      },
      build: {
        commands: [
          "printenv",
          'echo "Assuming role: $DEPLOY_ROLE"',
          "set -e",
          'echo "Current stage: $STAGE"',
        ],
      },
    },
    cache: {
      paths: [
        "node_modules/**/*",
        "**/node_modules/**/*",
        "web/.next/cache/**/*",
        "/root/.pnpm-store/**/*",
      ],
    },
  }),
  environment: {
    buildImage: codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_7_0,
    privileged: true,
    environmentVariables: {
      DOCKER: { value: "true" },
      NODE_OPTIONS: { value: "--max_old_space_size=8192" },
      TEST_ROLE: { value: deploymentRoles.test },
      PROD_ROLE: { value: deploymentRoles.prod },
      DEPLOY_ROLE: { value: deploymentRoles.test },
      STAGE: {
        type: codebuild.BuildEnvironmentVariableType.PLAINTEXT,
        value: "#{variables.stage}",
      },
    },
  },
  role: buildRole,
});

printenv inside the stage and on container retrieves STAGE=#{variables.stage} which I was expecting it to resolve to the pipeline variable. How should I do that?
